# How to retrieve desired records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Input Table** : Regions

```
    +---------------+---------------+---------- +-----------+
    | Child         | Parent        | Level     |  levelname|
    +---------------+---------------+---------- +-----------+
    | All Region    | All Region    | 1         |  national |
    | Africa Region | All Region    | 2         |   region  |
    | America       | All Region    | 2         |   region  |
    | Asia          | All Region    | 2         |   region  |
    | Europe Region | All Region    | 2         |   region  |
    | Africa        | Africa Region | 3         | Subregion |
    | Asia Pacific  | Asia          | 3         | Subregion |
    | Europe        | Europe Region | 3         | Subregion |
    | North America | America       | 3         | Subregion |
    | South America | America       | 3         | Subregion | 
    | Argentina     | South America | 4         |   Country |
    | Australia     | Asia Pacific  | 4         |   Country |
    | Pakistan      | Asia Pacific  | 4         |   Country | 
    | South Africa  | Africa        | 4         |   Country |
    | Tunisia       | Africa        | 4         |   Country | 
    | Uruguay       | South America | 4         |   Country |
    +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here , regions are of 4 levels

- All region
- Region
- Sub Region
- Country

  they have 0,1,2 and 3 ancestors,such as a country has subregion,region and allregion as ancestors ,suppose we give "Uruguay" ,then output will be South America, America , All Region.

Now, I need a query for this table,which will retrieve all ancestors for a given "child"

Comment: And where did you get stuck? What have you tried? Please remember, StackOverflow is no free coding service.

Comment: Do a four-table-self-join to get all four levels in a single row or a recursive query to get them in rows.

Comment: That print of the table looks suspiciously like MySQL (which is not SQL-Server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is a recursive CTE:

```
With recRegions AS
(
    /*Recursive Seed*/
    SELECT
        Child,
        Parent,
        Level,
        0 as Depth,
        CAST(Child as VARCHAR(5000)) as Path
    FROM
        Regions
    WHERE 
        Child=<WhateverChildYouAreWanting>

    UNION ALL

    /*Recursive Term*/
    SELECT
        Regions.Child,
        Regions.Parent,
        Region.Level,
        recRegions.Depth + 1,
        recRegions.Path || '>' || Region.Child
    FROM
        recRegions
        INNER JOIN Regions on
            recRegions.parent = Regions.Child
    Where recRegions.Depth < 10
)

Select Parent as Ancestors FROM recRegions;
```

Recursive queries can be a little tricky to wrap your head around at first, but if you break up the pieces of it, it makes sense:

1. Recursive Seed - This is the part where we get the first term we are after. In your case, we just want the record where the Child is the country you are wanting to query.
2. Recursive Term - This is the part where the query refers back to itself. It joins the recursive CTE `recRegions` to your `Region` table, connecting the child to the parent. The DB will hit this recursive term until no more records come back, which means we've climbed all the way up your hierarchy.
3. The final select statement just pulls back the records from your recursive query. You wanted all the ancestors, so that would be all of the `Parent` field records.

Generally when you see a table with a layout `child | parent | attributes | of | that | relationship` you can turn to the super powerful recursive CTE to make quick sense out of it all.

As @dnoeth mentioned in your Q's comments, you could also join Regions table to itself 4 times since your hierarchy seems to be only 4 deep. A recursive query doesn't care about depth though, so if you add more depth to your hierarchy, you won't have to edit your SQL to pull the ancestors.

---

Updated to add a "Depth" field to track recursions and stop after 10. Also added a "Path" field to track the hierarchy as it's built up from the Child. If you have an issue with your hierarchy cycling (a child reporting to a parent that reports to the child causing an endless loop) then you can use the following SQL statement instead of the `SELECT parent FROM` version above:

```
 SELECT * FROM recRegions;
```

Now you will see Path and Depth of each node of your hierarchy so you can fix your data, or the recursive CTE to avoid the cycling.

Comment: Wonderful example and explanation!

Comment: @JNveill On execution it shows "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion",I think it enters in infinite loop,would you please check this?

Comment: @Zahid I've updated to stop the recursions after we hit 10 deep. I've added field named `Depth` that will track how deep we are in recursion and kill the recursive term via the `WHERE` clause. My guess is that you have a child that reports to a parent that reports to the original child (This is called "Cycling" and it's not fun to deal with). I'm also adding a "Path" field that will track the parent/child relationships as the recursion progresses so you can find out where the cycle is.

Comment: As I look at your data, it looks like that "All Regions" reports to "All Regions". I'm betting that's where you cycle is hitting. To avoid just add to the WHERE statement on the recursive term `Parent <> "All Regions"`. So the recursion will stop.

Comment: 'recRegions.Path || '>' || Regions.Child', it gives the error: Incorrect syntax near '|'.